# image not rendering properly (weird orange grain)

Tags: rendering

so, every time I try to render my image, i just get a bunch of orange noise. i can't even see the image I'm trying to view[image: screenshot]

Comment: What was your expected render? Can you add a picture of your viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the outliner. Select your camera. Go to field of view (FOV) and check it says 35mm. Then go to the depth of field, uncheck it to render. If it renders, go back and re-check field of view, type 24mm and check results.
Also, on the N -panel on the viewer uncheck depth of field.

Thank you for your consideration to choose this as the correct answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: i don't understand, i try to go to the depth of field, but I don't see anything to "uncheck".

Answer (score 0):

You're using Cycles and that's normal for it (**lots of** calculations) with materials such as glass or when your object is complex/large, of which the progress bar is the proof. If your **final** render is OK nothing bad happens.